# Join multiple records to one row?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my DB Structure:

```
Users {User ID 1}
Roles {For example 2 roles: 1, 2}
User_roles {User ID 1: has Role 1, User ID 1: Has role 2}
```

How can I use join to get both of the roles since this Query duplicate the user:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `user_roles` ON (`users`.`id` = `user_roles`.`user_id`)
```

And I want to output a table that will look like that:

```
User ID | Has Role 1 | Has Role 2
--------|------------|-----------
1       |    yes     |    yes
```

Comment: use `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;` this command show you the exact structure and then display it here. Show us the `Users, Roles and User_roles` exact DB structure.

Comment: Users has ID, and some additional data,
User_roles has only 2 columns (user_id & role_id)

Comment: @DinRevah Your DB Structure in your post is not equal in your comment, update the post and show the db structure exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could group by user's id.

```
SELECT 
    `users`.`id`, 
     IF(SUM(`roles`.`id` = 1), 'yes', 'no') AS `Has Role 1`,
     IF(SUM(`roles`.`id` = 2), 'yes', 'no') AS `Has Role 2`
FROM `users` 
LEFT JOIN `user_roles` ON `users`.`id` = `user_roles`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `roles` ON `roles`.role_id = `user_roles`.`role_id`
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
```

And if you just use the role's pk, then you may omit `LEFT JOIN roles` by

```
SELECT 
    `users`.`id`, 
     IF(SUM(`user_roles`.`role_id` = 1), 'yes', 'no') AS `Has Role 1`,
     IF(SUM(`user_roles`.`role_id` = 2), 'yes', 'no') AS `Has Role 2`
FROM `users` 
LEFT JOIN `user_roles` ON `users`.`id` = `user_roles`.`user_id`
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
```

Comment: Just one question, what would happen if the user has both roles? Is possible on your plans?

Comment: @Olvathar Yes, both will be `yes` in that case.

Comment: I must be wrong in something, but, SUM() wouldn't be 3?

Comment: @Olvathar No, it won't, just test it yourself.

Comment: Finally I've tested and seen it, really interesting the condition inside sum(), learning a lot, thank you @xdazz I wasn't able to see nothing but IF(SUM(role_id) = 1, yes, no)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT
    usr.UserId,
    CASE WHEN role.HasRole1 = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS HasRole1,
    CASE WHEN role.HasRole2 = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS HasRole2
FROM users AS usr
LEFT JOIN user_roles AS role ON usr.id = role.user_id
```

Comment: There is no such column like `HasRole1` in op's table structure.